# A lot of process named "cron" were generated by "launchd" process in MacOS Catalina 10.15.2

Tags: macos, cron, launchd, macos-catalina

After upgrading to the Catalina, My Macbook Pro sometimes will become out of memory which cannot relocate any memory to open new windows or application, the only solution was reboot the OS.

Today, I discovered, in [Activity Monitor], a new "cron" process will be generated every minute. I quitted some of the "cron" processes by [Activity Monitor], then the OS got back to normal -- the memory were released.

The parent process of these "cron" processes is "launchd", which I think is the very initial process of the whole OS.

I don't have any cron job configured in the crontab.

How can I find the application or process which generates the "cron" process?

or

How can I stop the "launchd" to generate so many "cron" process?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I found this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372522/cron-processes-piling-up), I did ignored a crontab which was setup long time ago.

By adding "&> /dev/null" to the end of the crontab command, the cron process was not generated.

But why this only happens when upgraded to the Catalina.